# Render component in test that has document.getElementById

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can i mock the document.getElementById

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

      68 | 
      69 |   componentDidMount() {
    > 70 |     document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundImage = "./images/background1.png";
         |     ^
      71 |     document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundSize = 'auto';
      72 |   }
```

I've tried to mock

```
const dummyElement = document.getElementById('main');
const style = {backgroundImage:"", backgroundSize:""}
const elem= jest.fn()
const getElementById = (elem)=>jest.fn()
```

simple test I'm trying to run

```
it('render with props', ()=>{
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
  })
```

I just want to render the component

Comment: Something like jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => document.createElement('div'));

Comment: Thank you for your quick solutions, it worked. write it as an answer so that i accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').mockImplementation(() => document.createElement('div'));
```

That should solve the issue for you.